# OSGI org.slf4j.impl dependency

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I'm new to OSGI (sorry) and having a few issues trying to deploy my package and related dependencies.

This is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.felix.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.felix.test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.4</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Export-Package>
                            com.felix.test.search
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>
                            ${project.artifactId}
                        </Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Activator>
                            com.felix.test.Activator
                        </Bundle-Activator>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Then I'm bundling this using the Maven command:

> mvn org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:bundleall

This is successful and generates my bundle as well as 3 dependency bundles:

- net.sf.ehcache_2.10.0.jar
- org.apache.commons.lang3_3.4.0.jar
- slf4j.api_1.7.7.jar

This seems OK and I can install and start the first two but when I try and start slf4j I get the following exception:

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [25](R
>   25.0): missing requirement [slf4j.api [25](R 25.0)] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.impl)(version>=1.6.0)) Unresolved
>   requirements: [[slf4j.api [25](R 25.0)] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.impl)(version>=1.6.0))]

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something very simple but can't pin it down. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slf4j has an unusual design (some might say a *bad* design, ahem). It is an API bundle that depends on an implementation package, namely `org.slf4j.impl`.

You need to install an additional bundle that implements the Slf4j API. There are lots of choices here... for example `slf4j-simple` is a basic implementation, whereas `slf4j-jdk14` uses the Java 1.4 `java.util.logging` back end, etc.

[Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) also contains an implementation of the API.

Answer (score 1):

Need to correct myself as slf4j indeed provides bundles now as Neil pointed out. Not sure how well it works though. I found some explanation [how to install slf4j for OSGi here](http://blog.dbfconsult.be/?p=5). It does not look very clean to me though. You need to create a bundle fragment for the configuration. Which means you can not change it at runtime.

So I still would rather recommend to use [pax-logging](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxlogging/Pax+Logging) at runtime instead. It implements the slf4j api as well as other logging APIs. As backend it uses log4j and configures it via config admin. So you do not need hacks for the logging config and can change it at runtime.

Comment: The bundle fragment is not needed either. You can ship the configuration file along with your application binaries and pass the location as a system property argument ("-D"; binding specific).

Comment: Out of interest, I tried switching to pax-logging but now getting the following when I try and start my bundle - `org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.felix.test [18](R 18.0): missing requirement [com.felix.test [18](R 18.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.ibm.uvm.tools) Unresolved requirements: [[com.felix.test [18](R 18.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.ibm.uvm.tools)]` any ideas?

Comment: Note sure what you did to get this required package. Slf4j and pax-logging should not need that. As I have read from your new question I think you are configuring the bundle plugin incorrectly.

Comment: @timothyclifford E.g. with a Java Util Logging binding you can use the following command line argument `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=<installation-dir>/<conf-dir>/logging.properties` or e.g. with a Log4J 2 binding you can use: `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=<installation-dir>/<conf-dir>/log4j2.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error message, and found out that it was due to bad bundle plugin configuration (as mentioned by @Christian_Schneider).

#### My situation

So i had roughly this error message when deploying on Karaf:

> missing requirement ... Unresolved requirements:  ... osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.impl

My modules *pom.xml* looked like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j_version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

...

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Private-Package>*</Private-Package>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

#### Solution

*credits @jbonofre from the karaf community*

I just repaced `<Private-Package>*</Private-Package>` with `<Export-Package></Export-Package>`, to get:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Export-Package></Export-Package>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and consequently the import of `org.slf4j.impl` in my bundles *manifest.mf* disappeared, leaving only an import to `org.slf4j`. This is provided by PAX Logging, which is installed by default on karaf.

Answer (score 0):

I am using **slf4j-api** bundle in my AEM local instance, and figure out this **slf4j-api** bundle in not Active status.
Issue pic
[image]

After googling many blogs & question post here, using this post I am able to resolve this issue

**Steps**

1. Download the **slf4j-simple** this jar bundle from [MVN Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple%20link)
2. Installed in my AEM local instance and after 30 sec refresh, this issue resolved